# JBoss AS 5 over WAS 7

Tags: jboss, websphere

Can someone please help with advantages of JBoss over WAS?

Any help or reference is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any good reason why two quite old versions are compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is one from](ftp://ftp.boulder.ibm.com/software/uk/pdf/WebSphere7vsJBoss5TCO.pdf) IBM website. Most of the comparisons I believe will be biased.

Here is another [discussion thread](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/What-is-difference-between-websphere-52795.S.51206396).

**NOTE:** The comparison should be done based on your use-cases and SLA requirements. Otherwise it is just theoretical.